# How to implement redis distributed cache in spring boot application which shall allow to query on cached data as like RDBMS

Tags: caching, redis, spring-data-redis, distributed-caching

I have 2 layer `spring` boot application as below and wish to implement distributed 2nd level cache with `redis` as to improve the performance . 
[Spring boot Architecture][1]
   Here we are using `kubernates` and hence there could be multiple instances of "Atomic Service A" and hence the requirement of distributed cache.
Though there could be few requests coming less frequently to modify the data in DB and same needs to be reflected in `cache`. 
Wondering if there is any standard solution with `redis` to fetch data as like from traditional `RDBMS` .
Here the hypothetical solution would be like on startup "Student Atomic Service A" shall load Student data from DB on `Redis cache` and then any subsequent delete/update shall first do the same in Db and then update in `Redis` also I should get the records from `Redis` the way we query `RDBMS`.
e.g `select * from student where id <10`

It would be great if anybody can point any hint of sample implementation here.

I have gone through various sites but they only talk about key value thing but wish to find a DB Query like solution where the queried result shall get returned from cache.
I have tried POC with `RedisTemplate` but do not find a api like the way we query to a DB can be made e.g. select * from student where id<=5

Do not see any `API` which shall allow me to do operations like `RDBMS` with `redis cache API`

Answer (score 1):

> Do not see any API which shall allow me to do operations like RDBMS
>   with redis cache API

Typical RDBMS ( like MySQL, Oracle etc.)  and Redis are different datastores with different data models and query language so they have virtually nothing in common except they are persistent data stores. You can have two different level of abstractions integrating with these data stores. One abstraction is at a repository level -  what framework like [Spring Data Redis](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-redis) provides.For Spring Data Redis repository check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.1.10.RELEASE/reference/html/#redis.repositories). Another abstraction is provided by framework like [Hibernate Data](https://hibernate.org/ogm/) which provides integration with Redis via [Hibernate OGM Redis](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-ogm-redis)
module. This is more close to what you are expecting as it will give you a rich JPQL query language ( which is very close to SQL except that it operates on Objects rather than tuples). This may be worth checking out.

Comment: I wonder how it can be used with springframework data and Hibernate OGM Redis  examples in git talks about jpa.It would be great if you have handy springboot +redis example for this where ogm is integrated? It would be of great help